# Commutativity of matrix and its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If a matrix is symmetric or skew-symmetric it commutes in the obvious way with its transpose.
(For symmetric: $SS^T=S^2$ and $S^TS =S^2$)

The less obvious is the case of commutativity  for orthogonal matrix but such matrix also commutes with its transpose because $RR^T=RR^{-1}= I= R^{-1}R=R^TR$.

**Questions:**

- Are there  other cases when a matrix commutes with its transpose ?
- What is the general property of such matrix which allows it to
  commute with its transpose ?

Comment: They are diagonalisable. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix

Comment: @Nephente  in the statement from wikipedia "a matrix is normal if and only if it is unitarily similar to a diagonal matrix" how to understand "unitarily"? It's enough for real matrices to notice "The real analogue of a unitary matrix is an orthogonal matrix"?

Comment: No, in general a normal matrix cannot be diagonalised by an orthogonal transformation, but only over the complex numbers by a unitary one. Take any non-trivial rotation in the plane for example. It is certainly normal, but has no _real_ eigenvalues. Of course there are real normal matrices that can be diagonalised by an orthogonal transformation. (Skew-) symmetric matrices are an example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Matrices for which $S^*S=SS^*$ holds are called *normal*. Here $*$ denotes the conjugate transpose. In the case of a real matrix this is equivalent to $SS^T=S^TS$.

Normal matrices are precisely the ones that are diagonalisable by a *unitary* transformation, i.e

$$ S = U^* D U $$ for $U$ unitary and $D$ diagonal.

Unitarity is in general a key property. Even if $S$ is real, an orthogonal transformation will not do in general. Take any non-trivial rotation in the plane for example. It is certainly normal, but has no real eigenvalues.
They can be *unitarily* diagonalised though.

On the other hand, (skew-) symmetric matrices are an example of real matrices that can be orthogonally diagonalised.

Several equivalent characterisations can be found for example on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix).

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but might be fun to read. Nephente's comment on normal matrices is an answer.

Suppose that a matrix $A$ commutes with it's transpose $A^T$. Let's calculate $(AA^T)_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}(a_{kj}^t)=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}a_{jk}$. View $A$ as a collection of rows $A_1, \dots ,A_n$. Then $(AA^T)_{ij}=\left\langle A_i,A_j \right\rangle$ where $\left\langle \cdot, \cdot \right\rangle$ denotes the standard inner product. In the same fashion $(A^TA)_{ij}=\left\langle C_i, C_j \right\rangle$ where $C_i$ is the $i$-th column of $A$. Hence $AA^T=A^TA$ implies that the inner product of the $i$-th row with the $j$-th row is the same of for the corresponding columns. In fact this characterizes normal matrices.

Comment: Hmm, the same can be said about about the inner product of the i-th column with the j-th column  and the inner product of the i-th row with the j-th row ... it originates almost from the definition of multiplication and transpose..

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. I'm not saying much and it is just rephrasing what it means to commute with the transpose. But it tells you that you can look at this multiplication as calculating inner products (which is often useful).

Comment: Your explanation has the advantage that is quite intuitive although very broad in fact, in contrast this concept of "normality" as explained in Wikipedia is much less intuitive.

Comment: We can write down your formula also as   

-   for any   $i,j$ :  
$({e_i}^TA){({e_j}^TA)}^T=(Ae_i)^T(Ae_j)$